# Using a text file as a set of values swift

Tags: ios, swift, set, text-files

I'm working on a project that selects one or more words contains entered(user) keywords.That's why I'm using a set. But the set is turkish dictionary. That is to say, it contains 68k words(most-used). How can I use datas from a text file to avoid overload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't very clear what you are asking.

If you want to load words from a text file you should look at using NSString's string parsing methods. The NSString method `componentsSeparatedByString:` will break a large string up into an array of pieces using the specified string as a delimiter. (You can use "\n" to separate words that are on separate lines, or " " to separate your words by spaces.)

If you want a set it's easy to load a set with the items in an array.

However I would recommend using an array and arc4random_uniform to select one of the items randomly.

Something like this

```
var working_array: = [String]()

let path = "your_path"
let textFile = NSString(
  contentsOfFile: path,
  encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding,
  error: nil)
let full_array = textFile.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
```

Loading array of random words

```
if working_array isEmpty
{
  working_array += full_array
}
```

fetching an element:

```
let random_index = arc4random_uniform(working_array.count)
a_word = working_array.removeAtIndex(random_index)
```